# What are the security pros/cons of a remote PostgreSQL database dump using SSH tunneling or using a local pg_dump client?

Tags: mysql, bash, postgresql, ssh, amazon-ec2

I want to automate a daily process to:

1. Dump 3 tables from a REMOTE postgresql database as INSERT only
   queries.
2. Add the data to a local MySQL database on an Amazon EC2
   instance.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support FDW to other databases so I cannot link the two databases together and need a BASH script executed daily.

The easiest way is to use the pg_dump client on the Amazon EC2 Instance (local) to connect to the remote PSQL database and do a dump to the local machine.

I am having a lot of trouble setting up the SSH tunnel because I am getting lots of trouble with port-forwarding (not every port is open on the local machine).  The other issue is I have to explicitly put the password in the bash script for the SSH tunnel to work.  If I can get ports open on the local machine then SSH tunneling could work.

Is it safer to do SSH Tunneling or is it better for the remote machine to open up a port and connect to the database with restricted permissions?  What are the pros and cons?

The following script is what I have:

```
#!bin/bash

TMPFILE='mktemp.sql'

sudo -E sshpass -p "poopspw123" \
ssh -fnNT -L 22:localhost:22 username@remotePSQL.com \
pg_dump -U poops \
--dbname=poops -t ppi_order -t poops_order_dates -t poops_price \
--column-inserts \
--data-only \
| awk '/^INSERT/ {i=1} /^SELECT/ {i=0} i' \
 > "$TMPFILE" \
 || (echo "pg_dump failed" 1>&2; exit 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that "ssh tunnelling" can mean here. One of them is OK, one is horrid.

You can tunnel TCP-in-TCP, running pg_dump on your local machine, connecting to a port on localhost that's forwarded to the remote PostgreSQL.

```
ssh -n -L 5433:localhost:5432 remote-box
pg_dump -p 5433 localhost -Fc -f dump-file.pgdump
```

That's what you seem to mean. Don't do this. Performance is generally not great and there's no good reason to do it.

---

You can use ssh to stream `pg_dump` output from a `pg_dump` invoked on the remote machine, e.g.

```
ssh remote-box pg_dump -Fc -f - > local-dump-file.pgdump
```

This performs better and avoids issues with dangling tunnels.

---

You can also make a direct libpq connection with `pg_dump`. If you have SSL set up on the remote instance this is the best option.

```
pg_dump "host=remote-box sslmode=require user=blah" -Fc -f dumpfile.pgdump
```

... but if you *don't* have SSL, you probably should run `pg_dump` over ssh and stream the results.

Comment: Thank you Craig for the response.  I was able to get it to work by performing the ssh action you presented.  I need to supply a password via SSH to perform this action.  I am using the sshpass command and explicitly supplying the password in the BASH script.  Is there a way to make this more secure?

Comment: @ramabrahma a .pgpass file or the `PGPASSWORD` env var

Comment: I have a .pgpass setup.  It's this portion I am concerned about:

sudo -E sshpass -p "poopspw123" \
ssh -fnNT -L 22:localhost:22 username@remotePSQL.com 

I have to supply a sudo sshpass to this and i don't want to.   Is there a way to hide it?  I think the alternative is to use Kamchybek's solution below.

Comment: @ramabrahma Ah, right. Yes, passwordless ssh via public key authentication is what you want here. You should also configure it so the ssh key used is *only* allowed to run `pg_dump` which you can do using `authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Passwordless scp/sftp comes to rescue:

1. You could generate private/public keys on your PostgreSQL server
2. You could add your public key onto your remote server
3. Write a bash script that will do pg_dump (or whatever action) and scp/sftp over to remove server.

> ```
> user@postgresql:~$ ssh-keygen
>
>
> user@postgresql:~$ ls .ssh/
> -rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1679 Dec 17 17:01 id_rsa
> -rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres  401 Dec 17 17:01 id_rsa.pub
> ```

The content of "id_rsa.pub" should be copied into "/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys" file on your remote server.